# Connect to teradata from SQL Server Managment Studio

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, ssms, teradata

I have an odbc source to teradata and I'm  successfully can connect to the database from R using RODBC package.

In my job place, I can connect to a SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio.

I was thinking, is there a way to write queries in SQL Server Management Studio interface from teradata like I'm writing queries now from many databases using R using RODBC package?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating linked server in SSMS.

Use below link for reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6d61861-b271-4d93-b14e-12ba9356798f/connect-to-oracle-via-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqltools

Comment: Use Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC, I was unable to make OLEDB Teradata driver to function fully.